# How to make list of files in Angular with http method get

Tags: angular, typescript

I make my first steps into Angular and i am stuck with listing all files in ClientApp.

I have a Web Api  on C# and GET request that shows all files in folder, but i dont know how to display that array in Angular.

```
[HttpGet]
    [Route("/getAllFiles")]
    public IEnumerable<string> GetAllFiles()
    {
        string folderName = "Upload";
        string webRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;
        string newPath = Path.Combine(webRootPath, folderName);
        List<string> files = new List<string>();
        DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(newPath);
        foreach (FileInfo fInfo in dirInfo.GetFiles())
        {
            files.Add(fInfo.Name);
        }
         return files.ToArray();
    }
```

I am trying to use this method, but i think i am wrong

```
return this.http.get(`https://localhost`)
```

Comment: You need to specify the server port and the endpoint: `this.http.get('https://localhost:3000/getAllFiles')`. (Assuming the port is 3000).

Comment: @TsvetanGanev i added url like this just for example, i think this is a bad code for my task

Comment: What makes you think "it is a bad code for your task" ?

Comment: @Pac0 because i want to transfer an  array and when i tried this , i have exception cannot GET

Comment: Your url is probably incorrect, as stated here in comments by Tsvetan and in my answer,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more a API server configuration ASP.NET routing problem, not really an Angular one.

**PORT NUMBER**

First, you need to know the port on which you API server runs.

The port is written like this : `https://localhost:portnumber`, like `https://localhost:8080`

**CORRECT ROUTE**

Secondly, in your C# / ASP.NET API code, your route is specified as `[Route("/getAllFiles")]` . This means that, if you want to go to this C# function, you need to attack this specific URL, like this :

`https://localhost:portnumber/getAllFiles`

**SUBSCRIBE TO OBSERVABLE**

(this does not seem to be your problem as per your last comment)

thirdly, the angular http service get method returns an Observable, which you should subscribe to of you want to acutally send a request.

```
const url = 'https://localhost:portnumber/getAllFiles';
this.http.get(url).subscribe(
    (result) => { 
         console.log(result); 
         // here you can assign the result to some private variable of your component,
         // and bind this variable to your template somehow
    },
    (error) => { console.log('an error occured!'); console.log(error); }
)
```

Comment: Ok i get it, but what should i transfer to html page?

Comment: you can save the result as a variable in your component (instead of `console.log()`, you can do `this.myResults = result;`), and in your HTML template use a `*ngFor` to create a list corresponding to your array.